# FFT differs between Python and C# implementations

Tags: python, c#, fft

I'm currently trying to calculate the cross correlation of two audio files using this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar) as a reference.

In python, the algorithm works as expected:

```
source, source_sample = librosa.load(SOURCE_PATH, sr = None)
target, _ = librosa.load(TARGET_PATH, sr = source_sample)

# this next power of two that is greater than len(source) + len(target)
DESIRED_LEN = 262144 

source = np.pad(source, (0, DESIRED_LEN - len(source)), 'constant')
target = np.pad(target, (0, DESIRED_LEN - len(target)), 'constant')

source_fft = scipy.fft.fft(source)
target_fft = np.fft.fft(target)
target_conj = np.conjugate(target_fft)
res = source_fft * target_conj
inverse = np.fft.ifft(res)

# yields the spot of greatest similarity
print(np.argmax(inverse))
```

Using C#, the algorithm doesn't work, because the results of the FFT are different.
I've tried FftSharp, FFTW and Mathnet.Numerics, all delivering the same result for FFT that is different from scipy/numpy (see table below).

```
using var sourceWav = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile);
var sourceSamples = sourceWav.ReadAsDoubles();
sourceSamples = FftSharp.Pad.ZeroPad(sourceSamples);
var fftSource = FftSharp.Transform.FFT(sourceSamples);
```

These are the results of FFT in comparison:

```
| Python (Scipy)  | .Net (FftSharp) | 
| --------------- | --------------- |
| -0.028 + 0j     | -0.028 + 0j     |      
|  0.027 + 0.071j |  0.074 - 0.016j |    
|  0.113 + 0.082j | -0.083 - 0.112j |    
|  0.223 + 0.006j | -0.104 + 0.197j |    
|  0.255 - 0.145j |  0.292 + 0.026j |
```

So, as all implementations in C# are the same, has this something to do with scaling/shifting? What do I have to do to transform the C# results into the numpy/scipy result to make the algorithm work?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit1:**

Yes, as stated above the input signal is read from the same Wav-File (for python via librosa, for C# its NAudio). I've double checked the values. They are the same in both environments.

I've added a image of the first 500 values of the FFT for python (left) nd C# (right). The results are of the same shape, but the right one seems more "dense". What's the problem here?

[image: Result of FFT. Left one: python, right one C#]

Comment: For the algorithm you calculate FFT of source and target. When comparring FFTs calculated in different languages/libraries, do you compare FFT of the same signal? Please show the full code for C# and for displaying (in both languages) coefficient arrays which you compare.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit above, the input signal is from the same wav file and the values are identical for both c# and python. I'm displaying the result of fft in python by using pyplot. For C#, I've calculated the FFT, wrote it to a csv file, read it in python and displayed it (image on the right).

Comment: My biggest suspicion is that you specified a desired length in python and not in C#. A dense FFT means that you have more points in the signal. So, even if this is quite late, can you still check?

Comment: I just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78079735/16815358. It might be relevant, or maybe not. Just in case you are ever back @Christoph