# Taking FFTW in MATLAB vs C/C++: Different outputs

Tags: c++, matlab, fftw

I am exploring the differences between fftw in MATLAB and C/C++. I think this maybe a straightforward question but for some reason I don't see it.

Assume the following MATLAB code:

```
Nx = 8;
Ny = 8;
Lx =16;
%-----------
xi_x =  (2*pi)/Lx;
xi  = ((0:Nx-1)/Nx)*(2*pi);
x =  xi/xi_x;
ylow = 0; 
yupp =6;  
ygl  = cos ( pi * ( 0 : Ny ) / Ny )';
ygl = (1/2)*(((yupp-ylow)*ygl) + (yupp+ylow));
[X,Y]   = meshgrid(x,ygl);
%define function u:
u = (Y-ylow) .* (Y-yupp) .* sin( (2*pi / Lx) * X);
uh = fft(u,[],2); 
%pad uh with zeros
uhp=[uh(:,1:Nx/2) zeros(Ny,(m-Nx)) uh(:,Nx/2+1:Nx)];
%take ifft
up=real(ifft(uhp,[],2)); 
u1 = real(ifft(uh,[],2)); %same as u
```

My question above since both `uh` and `uhp` are the same values with extra zero padding, why is the inverse of fft of these two different? Meaning if `uh` is:

```
0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 5.2721i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 5.2721i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +18.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -18.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +30.7279i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -30.7279i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +36.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -36.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +30.7279i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -30.7279i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +18.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -18.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 5.2721i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 5.2721i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

and `uhp` is:

```
0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 5.2721i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 5.2721i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +18.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -18.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +30.7279i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -30.7279i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +36.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -36.0000i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +30.7279i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -30.7279i
  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 +18.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 -18.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 5.2721i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.0000 - 5.2721i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
```

Then why the  `real(ifft(uh,[],2))` equals:

```
    0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -0.9320   -1.3180   -0.9320   -0.0000    0.9320    1.3180    0.9320
   -0.0000   -3.1820   -4.5000   -3.1820   -0.0000    3.1820    4.5000    3.1820
         0   -5.4320   -7.6820   -5.4320   -0.0000    5.4320    7.6820    5.4320
   -0.0000   -6.3640   -9.0000   -6.3640   -0.0000    6.3640    9.0000    6.3640
         0   -5.4320   -7.6820   -5.4320   -0.0000    5.4320    7.6820    5.4320
   -0.0000   -3.1820   -4.5000   -3.1820   -0.0000    3.1820    4.5000    3.1820
         0   -0.9320   -1.3180   -0.9320   -0.0000    0.9320    1.3180    0.9320
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

and `up=ifft(uhp,[],2);`  is:

```
 0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0   -0.4393   -0.7610   -0.8787   -0.7610   -0.4393   -0.0000    0.4393    0.7610    0.8787    0.7610    0.4393
   -0.0000   -1.5000   -2.5981   -3.0000   -2.5981   -1.5000   -0.0000    1.5000    2.5981    3.0000    2.5981    1.5000
         0   -2.5607   -4.4352   -5.1213   -4.4352   -2.5607   -0.0000    2.5607    4.4352    5.1213    4.4352    2.5607
   -0.0000   -3.0000   -5.1962   -6.0000   -5.1962   -3.0000   -0.0000    3.0000    5.1962    6.0000    5.1962    3.0000
         0   -2.5607   -4.4352   -5.1213   -4.4352   -2.5607   -0.0000    2.5607    4.4352    5.1213    4.4352    2.5607
   -0.0000   -1.5000   -2.5981   -3.0000   -2.5981   -1.5000   -0.0000    1.5000    2.5981    3.0000    2.5981    1.5000
         0   -0.4393   -0.7610   -0.8787   -0.7610   -0.4393   -0.0000    0.4393    0.7610    0.8787    0.7610    0.4393
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

The reason I ask b/c in C/C++ when padding my arrays similarly and taking the ifft my code returns the same output, so `real(ifft(uh,[],2))` = `real(ifft(uhp,[],2))`!

Here's my C/C++ code:

```
static const int nx = 8;
static const int ny = 8;
static const int ncomp = 2;
static const int nxk = nx/2 + 1;
static const int Mx = 3*nx/2, My= 3*ny/2;
double makeSpatialMesh2DTrans(double dx, double dy, double ylow, double yupp,double xarr[], double yarr[]);
int xy(int x, int y, int number_of_cols);
class MyFftwClass {
public:
    MyFftwClass(void);
    ~MyFftwClass(void);
    void r2cexecute(double rArr[], double cArr[][ncomp]);

private:
    static fftw_plan s_plan; 
    double *m_buffer_in;
    fftw_complex *m_buffer_out;
    
};
class MyiFftwClass { //inverse
public:
    MyiFftwClass(void);
    ~MyiFftwClass(void);
    void c2rexecute(double cArr[][ncomp],double rArr[]);

private:
    static fftw_plan s_plan1;
    fftw_complex *m_buffer_in1;
    double *m_buffer_out1;
};
MyFftwClass r2c;
MyiFftwClass c2r; 
int main(){ 
double Lx = 16.;    
double ylow = 0.;
double yupp = 6.;
double Ly = (yupp-ylow);
double dx = Lx / nx;
double dy = Ly / ny;
double *XX;
XX = (double*) fftw_malloc((nx*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
memset(XX, 42, (nx*(ny+1)) * sizeof(double));  
double *YY; 
YY = (double*) fftw_malloc((nx*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
memset(YY, 42, (nx*(ny+1)) * sizeof(double)); 

double kmax = makeSpatialMesh2DTrans(dx, dy, ylow, yupp, XX, YY);
double *uFun; 
uFun = (double*) fftw_malloc((nx*(ny+1))*sizeof(double));
double A = 2*M_PI/Lx;
for(int y = 0; y< ny+1; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x< nx; x++){
            uFun[xy(x, y, nx)] = ( (YY[xy(x, y, nx)]-ylow) * (YY[xy(x, y, nx)]-yupp) * sin(A*XX[xy(x, y, nx)]));
        }
    }
}

fftw_complex *uFunk;
uFunk = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc((nx*(ny + 1)) * sizeof(fftw_complex));
memset(uFunk, 42, (nx*(ny + 1))* sizeof(fftw_complex));
    r2c.r2cexecute(uFun,uFunk);

    double N[2] = {nx,ny};
    double M[2] = {Mx,My};


    fftw_complex *uFunk_pad;
    uFunk_pad = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc((Mx*My)* sizeof(fftw_complex));
    
    //Add zero padding to the function u 
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    for(int y=0; y<ny+1; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<Mx; x++){
            if(x<nxk && y<ny){ 
                uFunk_pad[xy(x, y, nx)][0] = uFunk[xy(x, y, nx)][0];
                uFunk_pad[xy(x, y, nx)][1] = uFunk[xy(x, y, nx)][1]; 
            }
            else{
                uFunk_pad[xy(x, y, nx)][0] = 0.0;
                uFunk_pad[xy(x, y, nx)][1] = 0.0;
            }
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << std::complex{uFunk_pad[xy(x, y, nx)][0], uFunk_pad[xy(x, y, nx)][1]} <<  ' ';
        }
          std::cout << "\n";
    }
    //Take ifft of padded inputs 
    double *f_pad; 
    f_pad = (double*) fftw_malloc((Mx*My)*sizeof(double));
    memset(f_pad, 42, (Mx*My)* sizeof(double));
  
    c2r.c2rexecute(uFunk_pad,f_pad);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    for(int y=0; y<ny+1; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<Mx; x++){
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << f_pad[xy(x, y, nx)] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
//free stuff

    }
int xy(int x, int y, int number_of_cols) { return x + y * number_of_cols; }
double makeSpatialMesh2DTrans(double dx, double dy, double ylow, double yupp,double xarr[], double yarr[]){
    for(int y = 0; y< ny+1; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x< nx; x++){ 
                xarr[xy(x, y, nx)] = x*dx; 
                yarr[xy(x, y, nx)] =  1. * cos(((y) * M_PI )/ny);
                yarr[xy(x, y, nx)] =  (1./2)*(((yupp-ylow)*yarr[xy(x, y, nx)]) + (yupp+ylow));
            
        }       
    }
        if (dx < dy){
            return 1/(2*dx);
        }else {
            return 1/(2*dy);
        }

}
MyiFftwClass::MyiFftwClass(void)
{
    m_buffer_in1 = fftw_alloc_complex(nx * (ny + 1));
    m_buffer_out1 = fftw_alloc_real((nx * (ny + 1))); 
    if (!(m_buffer_in1 && m_buffer_out1))
    {
        throw new std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate memory!");
    }
    if (!s_plan1)
    {
        s_plan1 = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(1,&nx, (ny+1),m_buffer_in1,nullptr,1,(nx),m_buffer_out1,nullptr,1, (nx), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        if (!s_plan1)
        {
            throw new std::runtime_error("Failed to create plan!");
        }
    }

}
MyiFftwClass::~MyiFftwClass(void)
{
    fftw_free(m_buffer_in1);
    fftw_free(m_buffer_out1);
}

void MyiFftwClass::c2rexecute(double cArr[][ncomp],double rArr[]) 
{
    memcpy(m_buffer_in1,cArr, sizeof(fftw_complex) * (nx * (ny + 1)));
    fftw_execute_dft_c2r(s_plan1, m_buffer_in1, m_buffer_out1); 
    memcpy(rArr, m_buffer_out1,sizeof(double) * (nx * (ny + 1)));
     // renormalize:
  for(int y = 0; y < ny + 1; y++) 
    for(int x = 0; x < nx; x++)
      rArr[xy(x, y, nx)] /= nx;
}

fftw_plan MyiFftwClass::s_plan1 = NULL;
MyFftwClass::MyFftwClass(void)
{
    m_buffer_in = fftw_alloc_real((nx * (ny + 1))); 
    m_buffer_out = fftw_alloc_complex(nx * (ny + 1));
    if (!(m_buffer_in && m_buffer_out))
    {
        throw new std::runtime_error("Failed to allocate memory!");
    }

   if (!s_plan)
    {
        s_plan = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(1,&nx, (ny+1),m_buffer_in,nullptr,1,(nx),m_buffer_out,nullptr,1, (nx), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
       
        if (!s_plan)
        {
            throw new std::runtime_error("Failed to create plan!");
        }
    }

    
}

MyFftwClass::~MyFftwClass(void)
{
    fftw_free(m_buffer_in);
    fftw_free(m_buffer_out);
}

void MyFftwClass::r2cexecute(double rArr[], double cArr[][ncomp])
MyFftwClass::execute(double *const in, fftw_complex *const out)
{
    memcpy(m_buffer_in, rArr,  sizeof(double) * (nx * (ny + 1)));
    fftw_execute_dft_r2c(s_plan, m_buffer_in, m_buffer_out);
    memcpy(cArr, m_buffer_out, sizeof(fftw_complex) * (nx * (ny + 1)));
}

fftw_plan MyFftwClass::s_plan = NULL;
```

Outputs of the C/C++ are:
For `uFunk` the output:

```
(0.000,0.000) (0.000,-0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(0.000,0.000) (0.000,5.272) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,18.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,30.728) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,36.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,30.728) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,18.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,5.272) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
```

and output of the padded function `uFunk_pad`:

```
(0.000,0.000) (0.000,-0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(0.000,0.000) (0.000,5.272) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,18.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,30.728) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,36.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,30.728) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,18.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(-0.000,0.000) (0.000,5.272) (-0.000,0.000) (-0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
(0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000) (0.000,0.000)
```

Then when taking the inverse of padded function `uFunk_padded`it returns the same value as `real(ifft(uh,[],2))` in MATLAB function and NOT `real(ifft(uhp,[],2))`:

```
0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.932 -1.318 -0.932
 0.000 -0.932 -1.318 -0.932 -0.000  0.932  1.318  0.932 -0.000 -3.182 -4.500 -3.182
-0.000 -3.182 -4.500 -3.182 -0.000  3.182  4.500  3.182 -0.000 -5.432 -7.682 -5.432
-0.000 -5.432 -7.682 -5.432 -0.000  5.432  7.682  5.432  0.000 -6.364 -9.000 -6.364
 0.000 -6.364 -9.000 -6.364 -0.000  6.364  9.000  6.364  0.000 -5.432 -7.682 -5.432
 0.000 -5.432 -7.682 -5.432 -0.000  5.432  7.682  5.432  0.000 -3.182 -4.500 -3.182
 0.000 -3.182 -4.500 -3.182 -0.000  3.182  4.500  3.182  0.000 -0.932 -1.318 -0.932
 0.000 -0.932 -1.318 -0.932 -0.000  0.932  1.318  0.932  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
```

Why is my C/C++ output not matching the one from MATLAB? Am I misunderstanding something fundamental? Thanks

Comment: There is no "C/C++", be very clear which language you want an answer for. Since you use classes remove the "C" tag

Comment: You post a lot of code. Try to simplify it down to a shorter bit of code that does just the IFFT (since you assume  that's where the issue is). Verify that the shorter code still shows a difference between a MATLAB and a C++ implementation. Then post that here. See [mre]. Also, make sure the C++ code has the include statements and everything else needed for us to compile it.

Comment: I assume very big similarities to the question I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070774/why-python-np-fft-fft-result-and-c-sharp-fourier-forward-result-different/78079735#78079735

Comment: Never mind, I thought your input matrix was complex...